# how to assign obj[key] to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to assign an empty obj with a variable [key] to an array and push the item to the array but for some reason it doesnt work properly. 
I wonder why the first item in the array is an empty string ? How to correctly assign it to an array.
Could any please advice ? thank you!

```
let online = {};
let users = [];
let userInRoom =[];


 socket.on('join', ({ username, room, uUID }, cb) => {


    if(room in online){
        if(!online[room].includes(username)){
            online[room].push(username);
        }

    }else{
        online[room]=[...userInRoom, username];
    }

    console.log("online", online, "users", users);
   //---> the console result ==> online { general: [ '', 'jiojoij' ] } users [ 'jiojoij' ]

 });
```

I wonder why the first item in the array is an empty string ? 
How to correctly assign it to an array.

Comment: @isherwood I wonder why the online { general: [ '', 'jiojoij' ] } .... after first push is an empty string ? How to correctly assign it to an array.

Comment: Because the first time it goes in the `else` branch, and you don't add any user in there (`userInRoom` is empty).

Comment: @Aioros Since OP is using spread operator and the array is empty, it won't go in as an empty string unless the array is`['']`..

Comment: @soulLess Good point

Comment: @Aioros that's why I try to concat it with username ...so that will still have to trigger the second push ?

Comment: Is there another part that you didn't paste here? Because right now `userInRoom` is always empty.

Comment: @soulLess I also tried not to assign to userInRoom, instead I directly do 
online[room]=[ username];

This still not work properly...

Comment: Are you sure `username` is never an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems a little confusing. What's the point of the `userInRoom` array if it's always empty?
I would try something like:

```
if (!(room in online)) {
    online[room] = [];
}
if (!online[room].includes(username)) {
    online[room].push(username);
}
```